# clear().sendKey() not working in <input ....> field

Tags: protractor

I am observing for my application `clear().sendKey("abc")` or `click().clear().sendKey("abc")` is not working. `clear()` does not clears the text present in `<input...>` field.

I tried this also :

```
    WSManager.EditWSName.then(function(){
  browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('a').perform().then(function(){
            browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE).perform().then(function(){
      WSManager.EditWSName.sendKeys(Renamed);
      browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    });        
  });
});
```

In this case previous text gets cleared but `sendKey()` does not type `"Renamed"` text in `<input ...>` field.

Answer (score 0):

`Renamed` field is not a string and not a variable either.

```
WSManager.EditWSName.sendKeys(Renamed);
```

**Solution:**

```
WSManager.EditWSName.sendKeys('Renamed');
```

Answer (score 0):

**.clear();** returns a promise that needs to be resolved.
Also, your code looks very confusing, or lacks context.
Anyway, this has always worked for me, when having to clear an input and then sendKeys afterwards:

```
element.clear()
  .then(function(){
      element.sendKeys('abc');
  });
```

Comment: "@joaquin Casco" i have tried your solution and many other ways, i could not clear a text field and write. it always append the text. Any suggestions please?

Comment: issue solved with the help from this link. if any face the same issue refer this. [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/301#issuecomment-32651201).